# AnyLogic: Replications in ParameterVariation - How are replications executed correctly?

Tags: anylogic

I am doing an parameter variation experiment in AnyLogic. There are only 2 different parameter settings in total. For each iteration, 5 replications should be used. I understand that this should produce a total of 10 results.
The results of each simulation are added to a dataset called "histogramDataset" (representing total costs). At the end of the 5 replications, I want the average of the results of this specific parameter setting to be displayed in an excel file. Then I delete the dataset and add the results of the new replications of the new parameter setting and would also like to have the average value of the total costs from this setting.

The following code can be found in the "Java actions" section:

Before each experiment run:   histogramData.reset();
After simulation run:         histogramData.add(root.totalCosts);
After iteration:              excelFile.setCellValue(histogramData.mean(), 1, (getCurrentIteration()+1);

After each iteration, I display the number of replication results added to the dataset. Now it is the case that not 5 simulation runs and their results are added to the dataset, but first 9 and then 1. This distorts the average results. Why are not 5 replications added in each case? Or how could I fix this?

Comment: Have you played with parallel-vs-sequential replications? May disturb your expectations, turn off parallel execution in the exp properties

Comment: Thank you very much, that solved my problem! I didn't know that the default setting is parallel evaluation! Thanks for that! :)